# Exhausted Resultset when calling a method inside the while(rset.next)

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I'm getting an Exhausted resultset form the following code.

I've tried a few different things now and can't find a solution,
if I don't call the songs method it works, but the songs method works when it's called, can't get my head around it, hoping I'm missing something simple.

```
public void refreshList() {

    rset = po.getProduct();

    if (plist.size() > 0) {
        for (int i = plist.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            plist.remove(i);
        }
    }
    try {
        while (rset.next()) {

            songs(rset.getString(1));
            CD c = new CD(alist);

            Product p = new Product(rset.getString(1), 
                    rset.getString(2),
                    rset.getString(3), 
                    rset.getDouble(4), 
                    rset.getDouble(5), 
                    rset.getInt(6),
                    rset.getString(7),
                    rset.getString(8),
                    rset.getString(9), 
                    rset.getDouble(10), c);
            plist.add(p);

        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}


  public void songs(String ID)
{
    rset = po.getSongs();
    alist = new ArrayList<Song>();
    try {
        while (rset.next()){
            Song s = new Song(rset.getString(1),
                    rset.getString(2), 
                    rset.getString(3));
            slist.add(s);
        }   
    } 
    catch (Exception ea) {
        System.out.println(ea);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < slist.size(); i++)
    {
        if(slist.get(i).getSong_id().equals(ID))
        {
            alist.add(slist.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is beacuse you are iterating through your `ResultSet` object in the `songs()` method. Either use seaparate `ResultSetObject` for both or better rewind your `ResultSet` object after calling `songs()` method

Comment: How would I rewind my results set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `refreshList` you have `while (rset.next())` loop, on each iteration of it you have `songs(rset.getString(1));`, which itself has `while(rset.next()`. This leads to result set exhaustion, because when you return from `songs()` you try to take some more data from the current `position` of result set, while in `songs()` you got out of `while (rset.next())` loop, i.e. retrieved all its rows. Consider refactoring your code to avoid nested loops based on result set.